# How to avoid repeated hashchange events with jquery bbq and dependent controls?

Tags: jquery, jquery-bbq

Say I've got three select boxes all of which are set up to `$.bbq.pushState` onChange. If the selects also have interdependencies (e.g. selecting a different model changes what colors are available) changing one select can result in `window.hashchange` firing multiple times: once from the initial change, and again for each of the dependent selects' change handlers.

If the hashchange handler is expensive (or not idempotent) this can be a problem. What's the best way to prevent this from happening?

Comment: maybe set a timeout whenever it fires for a few seconds to prevent it firing again